# HTTP request over provided stream

Tags: .net, http, https

I want to perform a HTTP(S) request, but handle the opening of the socket connection separately from the .NET HTTP client stack. The API that would work for me should look like this:

```
new HttpWebRequest(Stream transportStream)
```

or perhaps

```
new HttpWebRequest(SslStream transportStream)
```

Standard .NET HTTP client does not seem to support this scenario. Does it? Do alternative HTTP clients for .NET that would allow it exist? I can only find wrappers for HttpWebRequest and friends. I'd very much like to avoid implementing rudimentary HTTP protocol parsing myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, I guess. I ended up using [Joyent's http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser) for response parsing - it wraps nicely with C++/CLI.